# Why not display the resolution value？

Tags: macos, display, resolution, ventura

**this is my settings menu:**
[image]

**and this is others settings menu:**

[image]

we are both Ventura:

[image]

[image]

What's happened?

Comment: Different systems. But not in English so not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry for language issue. I can set a specific app into English, but only "System Settings" can't. I don't know why is it invalid. @SolarMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on a icon (or control+click), you will see this:
[image]

Click on "Afficher la liste" (probably *Display the list* in english) and you see this:

[image]

And if you right-click on an item of the list, you will see "Display the thumbnails" to return to the default view of the settings.

Comment: Oh, You are right! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The first version is because the Mac has recognised a Retina display is connected.

The second is either not Retina, or is not registering correctly.
Google turns up very few hits for the PH27AQ2, but it would appear to be a 2k screen, 27" 2560 x 1440. This is not a retina display.

- With a retina display, you don't actually change the resolution, you change the apparent size on screen. The full resolution is always in use.
- With a non-retina, the actual pixel display is changed to the set resolution; there is no sub-pixel rendering.